# Multi vendor products, single store?

Tags: commerce

How can I create products in Drupal8 eCommerce, which are from different vendors, but I'm handling it trough a single store ?
(Vendors should be invisible to the end customer).

I want in addition to keep track internally (for my own accounting purposes) which item from which vendor was sold, so I can reimburse the specific vendor.
Is there a way to put/attach "out-of-bound" info to products and eventually orders ?

I'm still in research phase, experimenting with Drupal. Is such thing possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. In the end even unlimited with custom code ..

To easily limit the access for a vendor to only his products, each one would need one or more product types, then you can apply the right permissions. Also I would add the vendor/user as a reference (field) to that product type.

There very good shipping methods, applicable for different countries etc.

Comment: the vendor does not have access to do anything.. i.e. i will manage everything for them. I needed only to track different vendors orders, sales etc..

Comment: where  can I read about product "TYPES". I've seen Variations and Attributes, but not types

Comment: You can also just add fields to the default product type (and orders) to keep track of "out-of-bounds" info. You have complete control over what you display and what's on data entry forms (different versions for public/internal, etc)

Comment: product types, are like content types. product types are fieldable, and can have attributes attached to them. each product is of a type, and can have variations.